# After my arrival to/in Prague

Tags: prepositions

*After my arrival to/in Prague, I will send you the message.*

I am not able to decide which prepositions fit in the context. I have made some Internet research but still not sure. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

They are both suitable, with some difference.

to - means that you arrived in the region of Prague, maybe in the city, maybe at an airport outside of the city...

in - means that you arrived inside the area of the city; e.g. you are already between the buildings